# Deleting a role in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I came up with this command similar to my createrole command. Everything works except the last line of code. I just don’t understand why it won’t delete. Every time I send the code, this error comes up: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: delete() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘name’. I am using the latest version of python and discord.py.

```
@client.command(aliases=['delrole'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def deleterole(ctx, *,role, reason=None):

    delrole = role
    guild = ctx.guild

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == delrole:
            await ctx.send(delrole)     
            await role.delete(name=delrole)
```

Comment: Please try removing the `name=delrole` so that your statement is `await role.delete()`. Works for me. Role already knows it's name.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try it

Comment: Thank you @DaveStSomeWhere it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of name=delrole and just leave it as role.delete(), This should delete the role! Add ctx.send(‘The role has been deleted’) to the end so you know when if the role was deleted. You can also deleted ctx.send(delrole) to make it more clean but, I left it.

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def deleterole(ctx, *,role, reason=None):

    delrole = role
    guild = ctx.guild

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == delrole:
            await ctx.send(delrole)     
            await role.delete()
            await ctx.send(f’The role {delrole} has been deleted!’)```
````